# Can't do a proper Redirect 301

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to do a redirect 301 from my old domain to a new domain. I tried as follows in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(default|index)\.(html|php|htm)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(default|main|index)\.(html|php|htm)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

Redirect 301 /folder/ http://www.newdomain.com
Redirect 301 /folder http://www.newdomain.com
Redirect 301 /folder/another-folder http://www.newdomain.com/new-folder/new-other-folder
Redirect 301 /folder/another-folder/ http://www.newdomain.com/new-folder/new-other-folder
Redirect 301 /folder/product.html http://www.newdomain.com/product
Redirect 301 /folder/other-product.html http://www.newdomain.com/new-other-product
</IfModule>
```

But it is not being redirected properly to each page or folder specified in the code above. My old site is in a folder.
I'm using Magento and need to redirect about 200 pages. I need redirect my old domain that is in a folder, to my new domain root and redirect all pages and folders to respective ones in my new domain. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoud mixing `Redirect` directive with `RewriteRule`.

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*(default|index)\.(html|php|htm)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)(default|main|index)\.(html|php|htm)$ http://www.newdomain.com.br/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^folder/?$ http://www.newdomain.com.br [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^folder/another-folder/?$ http://www.newdomain.com.br/new-folder/new-other-folder [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^folder/product\.html$ http://www.newdomain.com.br/product [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^folder/other-product\.html$ http://www.newdomain.com.br/new-other-product [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com.br/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: I tried as you told me, but when I tried to go for example to www.olddomain.com/folder/another-folder, it should take me to www.newdomain.com/new-folder/new-other-folder, but instead it is taking me to www.newdomain.com/folder/another-folder. The most of my folders, subfolders and product names are a little bit different on new domain. Can you check, please?

Comment: Unfortunately it remains the same way. Maybe some server config is interfering?

Comment: 1. Cache cleared. 2. I forgot to mention that are different host. New server/host is running on nginx.

Comment: Does `/folder/` have another .htaccess? Is your root .htaccess exactly as shown in my answer?

Comment: Man, you saved my day! My .htaccess was in /folder/ and there was another .htacess on root. I changed it to root and voila!

Comment: After some weeks I checked in google webmasters tools and verified a lot of 404. E.g.: www.newdomain.com/store/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=60&dir=desc&limit=15&mode=grid&order=price&p=2&q=makita. But I think this was crawled in the old domain and are redirecting to the new domain now. Is there some generic rule to redirect all the others dynamic generated searchs to a specific page like home page on new domain without drop my ranking on google? On my new domain, dynamic search pages have been blocked in robots.txt. Thanks in advance.